# Does ROS support this scenario off-the-shelf?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building a mobile robot which is going to search for and collect small items in easily traversable environment with approximate map known beforehand. Robot will be equipped with a simple 2 DOF manipulator to pick, hold and deposit an item into a single stationary storage box. I will have my own vision software to detect the items to collect and course obstacles, and I will have a ROS driver for my wheeled platform and manipulator. Is there an off-the-shelf module in ROS, which allows for high level solution to this scenario? Do I have to write a lot of glue code and use multiple ROS modules: planner, navigation, mapping, etc.?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199343/does-ros-support-this-scenario-off-the-shelf?/) by [Paul Jurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/9766/paul-jurczak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the core assumptions of ROS is the understanding of ROS as a toolbox, not framework. Therefore ROS provides you with many powerful tools that can help you to quickly create solutions for various problems/applications that can be thought off. ROS is flexible and most tools are not created for a specific application. However, this includes that ROS does not provide solutions for a specific application of-the-shelf. You as a ROS user are still the one to create the solution.

For your scenario I think ROS could help a lot, I think you won't have to write to much glue code for the existing ROS modules but you will still have to provide some input (sensors? map?) and for the interaction between navigation and manipulation etc. I think you'll also be moreless on your own.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3